# Is the norm of a vector given by dividing it by the square root of the inner product with itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I've known the norm (aka. unit vector in the direction of) a vector (let's call it $v$) to be given  by the formula: $v/\sqrt{v \cdot v}$, where $\cdot$ is the dot product.

But can this be generalized to inner products, such that the norm the norm of a vector can be found by $v/\sqrt{< v,v>}$, where $<v,v>$ is the vector's inner product with itself? (since the dot product is an inner product this definition would agree with the previous one)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt{v\cdot v}$ and $\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$ are the norm of $v$. What you have there are unit vectors.

Comment: No: $v/\sqrt{v\cdot v}$ is the normalised vector associated to $v$, i.e. the vector which is collinear to $v$, but which has norm $1$.

Comment: See [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norms_on_inner_product_spaces)